# Apache camel multicast FreeMarker

Tags: java, apache-camel, freemarker, multicast, endpoints

I need to send two different XMLs (by FreeMarker) to two different endpoints.
i.e.

```
.to("freemarker:templates/xml1.ftl").to("file://C:\\testXmls1")
```

and

```
.to("freemarker:templates/xml2.ftl").to("file://C:\\testXmls2")
```

I had a look at the `multicast()` function but I don't know how to apply it when there are two .to

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can specify multiple endpoints in the same .to(uri1, uri2, ...) then it becomes as a single "eip".

```
multicast()
  .to(uri1a, uri1b)
  .to(uri2a, uri2b)
.end() // to end multicast
```

Otherwise you would have to enclose it using the pipeline eip.

```
multicast()
  .pipeline().to(uri1a).to(uri1b).end() // to end this pipeline
  .pipeline().to(uri2a).to(uri2b).end() // to end this pipeline
.end() // to end multicast
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed Claus