# apache camel multicast converting text message to byte message

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, multicast

I am trying to publish a text message to topic using apache camel with activemq.
Following code works fine and my client program is able to convert message to text message.

```
    <route id="setText">
                <from uri="restlet:///test/{testId}?restletMethod=POST" />
                <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly" />
                <setBody>
                    <simple>${header.testId}:${body}</simple>
                </setBody>
                <to uri="activemq:topic:TestTopic" />
            </route>
```

Now I added multicast to do multiple operations. multicast is able to perform well and send message to topic successfully.

```
    <route id="setText">
                        <from uri="restlet:///test/{testId}?restletMethod=POST" />
                        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly" />
                    <multicast>
                        <pipeline>
                        <!-- some operation -->
                        </pipeline>
                        <setBody>
                            <simple>${header.testId}:${body}</simple>
                        </setBody>
                        <to uri="activemq:topic:TestTopic" />
                    </multicast>
</route>
```

But while sending text message to topic, multicast is converting message to byte stream. My client program is unable to convert the consumed message to TextMessage bcoz the message is in bye format and below is the information displayed for system.out.println(at my client program)

```
ActiveMQBytesMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:R-014-49827-1433324560754-3:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:R-014-49827-1433324560754-3:1:1:1, destination = topic://TestTopic, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1433324582980, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1433324582981, brokerOutTime = 1433324583731, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@10d42d49, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@59e91c40, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {breadcrumbId=ID-R-014-49826-1433324557692-2-1, org_DOT_restlet_DOT_http_DOT_version=1.1, testId=3100026, org_DOT_restlet_DOT_startTime=1433324582521, CamelHttpMethod=PUT, CamelHttpUri=http://localhost:8080/service-bus/test/3100026}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null }
```

Can you suggest why multicast is converting text message to byte format? And what to do send message in text format? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multicast is certainly *not* converting anthying. You're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes. I understand it. it just pass the input information to all sub systems. But when I tested with out multicast, my client program is able to consume the message as TextMessage. But this is not happening in case of multicast.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of camel you are on, but I have seen a similar issue with the jaxb dataformat converting messages to bytes.  I would recommend opening a jira ticket.  In the meantime a work around I used previously was to enforce the text type on the jms endpoint.

```
activemq:topic:TestTopic?jmsMessageType=Text
```

Reference:
http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with multicast and jaxb unmarshalling. Without the multicast, unmarshal() works fine and I receive the expected Object type as parameter to the method "Handler.received(Object)".
Adding the unmarshal() behind a multicast, and "Handler.received(Object)" gets a Byte[] instead.

```
// works - Handler.received(Object) receives correct object type:
from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").unmarshal(jaxb).to("class:com.test.Handler?method=received");

// doesn't work - Handler.received(Object) receives a byte array:
from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").multicast().unmarshal(jaxb).to("class:com.test.Handler?method=received");
```

I'm a complete newbie to Camel and this has been driving me crazy the whole day.
The solution suggested above setting jmsMessageType to "Text" doesn't work for me either. In that case the Handler class receives a String containing the XML, as if the unmarshal() didn't do anything at all.

EDIT:
I looked at the following StackOverflow question:
[Apache camel multicast FreeMarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471945/apache-camel-multicast-freemarker?rq=1)

And changed my code to use "pipelines" like the example from user "Claus Ibsen":

```
from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").multicast()
.pipeline().to("file://targetdir/received").end()
.pipeline().unmarshal(jaxb).to("class:com.test.Handler?method=received").end()
.end();
```

And now it works just like I would expect it to. The received XML file is copied into "targetdir/received" and the method "Handler.received(Object)" gets the correct object type as parameter.
Thanks Claus!  :)